# addEventListener works in simple for loop but doesn't work with for-in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, addeventlistener, for-in-loop

When I use simple for loop, addEventListener works well in for loop.

But when I use for-in loop, it makes error like

> Uncaught TypeError: checklist[i].addEventListener is not a function

This is my work-well code.

```
var checklist = document.querySelectorAll(".checklist");
for (var i = 0, len = checklist.length; i < len; i += 1) {
  checklist[i].addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    alert('test');
  });
}
```

This is my Error code.

```
var checklist = document.querySelectorAll(".checklist");
for (var i in checklist) {
  checklist[i].addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    alert('test');
  });
}
```

I don't know what is difference between two codes.
Please Help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `for-in` loop iterates over all enumerable properties of an array or object. So, if you log your variable in console you'll see that along with the indexes of the elements you also get other properties like `length`, `keys`, `values` of the array and `checklist[length]` or `checklist[keys]` are not DOM elements. So you can't add an event listener to them.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I can understand what are that properties under my elements. Have a nice day!